# Как узнать с компьютера, что другой компьютер находится в другой подсети

Tags: сеть, cisco-packet-tracer, подсети

Всем привет! Есть такая топология:[image: топология]

Стоит задание узнать с терминала PC8 (отмечено красным), находится ли PC9 (отмечено синим) в разных подсетях. Есть ответ узнать это с помощью TTL при ping (если 127 - в разных подсетях, если 128 - то в одних), но существует еще какой-то способ, знает ли кто-то про него?

Comment: Взять из ifconfig маску подсети и наложить ее на свой и чужой IP

Comment: @avp а мы разве можем из терминала получить доступ к ipconfig другого компа (не настраивая никаких телнетов)? Просто если я правильно понял, то у нас в принципе маски могут быть разные на этих компах, что не дает сравнить адреса сети.

Comment: Я имел в виду ifconfig своего компа (если маски разные, то да, может получиться, что один считает, что компы в разных подсетях, а другой наоборот. Как это противоречие правильно разрешить -- решать вам. В принципе (если настроено) чужой ifconfig можно прочесть по ssh (нужен ли такой геморрой, решать вам))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует утилита [Traceroute](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute#:%7E:text=Traceroute%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0,%2C%20TCP%2C%20ICMP%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20GRE.), которая позволяет проследить маршрут следования данных.

В Windows для просмотра маршрута необходимо использовать команду `tracert`.

Так, в моём случае команда `tracert 192.168.133.3` даёт ответ:
[image: маршрут до 192.168.133.3]

Мы можем увидеть, что сначала идет ICMP запрос на маршрутизатор, а только потом уже на получателя, что значит, что два устройства находятся в разных подсетях.

Для сравнения приведу результат запроса для устройств в одной подсети `tracert 192.168.13.3`:

[image: маршрут до 192.168.133.3]